# Joining three tables to create parent - child

Tags: join, parent-child, guid

This week ive been landed with a task of transforming a extract from a database into something usable in sharepoint (my acctual specialism)

for this i need to assign GUID (NEWID()) to unqiue elements of an address field.

I have 'atomised' the RAW_CSV table into trans_area and trans_subarea and need to copy the trans_area.area_guid to the trans_subarea.subarea_pguid it illustrate the subarea's parent.

using the amazing resource of brains on SO ive written to this point:

`SELECT DISTINCT area_guid
FROM trans_area
JOIN IBS_RAW_CSV ON trans_area.area_id = IBS_RAW_CSV.Area_id
JOIN trans_subarea ON IBS_RAW_CSV.SubArea_Name = trans_subarea.subarea_name`

which IS giving me the GUID im looking for but im not convinced im going along the right path. Id really appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

My previous database knowledge was in LAMP evironments many moons ago.

Answer (score 0):

OK After more looking, i tidied up and tweaked it to this:

```
    UPDATE sa
SET sa.subarea_pguid = ta.[area_guid] 
FROM trans_area as ta
JOIN IBS_RAW_CSV AS ibs
ON ta.area_id = ibs.Area_id
JOIN trans_subarea AS sa 
ON ibs.SubArea_Name = sa.subarea_name
```

which does the job!